# Does the ability to factor in polynomial time give you smooth numbers in the number field sieve?

Tags: computer-science, sieve-theory

I have read that despite strong connections between prime factorization and DLP an algorithm for the former does not imply the latter directly. But I was reading about the number field sieve and it seemed like the bottleneck was identifying smooth norms. Wouldn't an ultrafast prime factorization algorithm achieve that?